# Use R to fill html/xml form and download the report file

Tags: html, r, xml, shiny, httr

## Goal

I am trying to automatically fill out this form and download commercial fisheries landings data (landing = https://foss.nmfs.noaa.gov/apexfoss/f?p=215:200:::::: , view source = view-source:https://foss.nmfs.noaa.gov/apexfoss/f?p=215:200:9856386363065::NO:::) through R.

## Variables (I think these are all of them?)

Below are some example inputs I would need to select in the website. I've tried to identify the what the user would see [User Selection Box Name]=[Example User Selection] and what the behind the scenes reads (looking at the devtools and source code) ([HTML ID]=[Example HTML Selection Code]). Hopefully, I got these right.

Year = "2011"  (P200_YEAR = "2011")

Region Type = "States" (P200_GEO_LOV = "1025")

States Landed = "Alabama" (P200_GEOGRAPHY = "01")

Species = "All Species" (P200_SPECIES = "ALL_SP")

RUN REPORT = [button] (P200_go = "")

Clicking the run report button displays the data in an interactive table. We can get all rows (or at least 100000 of them) of the data by selecting "All" rows (p200_interactive_report_row_select = "100000"). I don't need to download the data, per se. If the data can be extracted and saved as an object on the page, that would be great.

If best practice will be to download the data each time, you need to select "1. Detailed Report" (p200_interactive_report_saved_reports), Click "Actions">"Downloads" from which a pop-up appears and I would select "CSV".

## Research

I've been scouring the internet for ideas on how to do this, but I haven't gotten to work well. I've made some progress following this StackOverflow post ([Download file after fill form with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564160/download-file-after-fill-form-with-r)) but it is still not quite right and I think the website they are querying from is quite a bit simpler.

## Environment

```r
library(httr)
# Warning message:
# package ‘httr’ was built under R version 3.4.3

library(tidyverse)
# -- Attaching packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
#   v ggplot2 2.2.1       v purrr   0.2.4  
# v tibble  2.0.1       v dplyr   0.8.0.1
# v tidyr   0.7.2       v stringr 1.3.1  
# v readr   1.1.1       v forcats 0.2.0  
# -- Conflicts -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- tidyverse_conflicts() --
#   x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
# x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
# Warning messages:
#   1: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
# 2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
# 3: package ‘tibble’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
# 4: package ‘tidyr’ was built under R version 3.4.3 
# 5: package ‘purrr’ was built under R version 3.4.3 
# 6: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
# 7: package ‘stringr’ was built under R version 3.4.4 

R.version.string
#[1] "R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"
```

## Attempted code

```r
POST(
  url = "https://foss.nmfs.noaa.gov/apexfoss/f?p=215:200:9856386363065::NO:::",
  encode = "multipart",
  body = list(
    P200_YEAR = "2011",
    P200_GEO_LOV = "1025", #state
    P200_GEOGRAPHY = "01", #Alabama
    P200_SPECIES = "ALL_SP", 
    p200_go = "", 
    p200_interactive_report_saved_reports = "301319959260891033", # 1. Detailed Report
    p200_interactive_report_row_select = 100000 #"All"
    ), verbose()
) -> res

# -> POST /apexfoss/f?p=215:200:9856386363065::NO::: HTTP/1.1
# -> Host: foss.nmfs.noaa.gov
# -> User-Agent: libcurl/7.56.0 r-curl/3.0 httr/1.3.1
# -> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
# -> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
#   -> Content-Length: 833
# -> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------eb5b05624e7c8110
# -> 
#   >> --------------------------eb5b05624e7c8110
# >> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="P200_YEAR"
# >> 
#   >> 2011
# >> --------------------------eb5b05624e7c8110
# >> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="P200_GEO_LOV"
# >> 
#   >> 1025
# >> --------------------------eb5b05624e7c8110
# >> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="P200_GEOGRAPHY"
# >> 
#   >> 01
# >> --------------------------eb5b05624e7c8110
# >> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="P200_SPECIES"
# >> 
#   >> ALL_SP
# >> --------------------------eb5b05624e7c8110
# >> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p200_go"
# >> 
#   >> 
#   >> --------------------------eb5b05624e7c8110
# >> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p200_interactive_report_saved_reports"
# >> 
#   >> 301319959260891033
# >> --------------------------eb5b05624e7c8110
# >> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p200_interactive_report_row_select"
# >> 
#   >> 1e+05
# >> --------------------------eb5b05624e7c8110--
#   
#   <- HTTP/1.1 200 
# <- Date: Mon, 12 Aug 2019 03:37:12 GMT
# <- Server: Apache
# <- Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
# <- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: floatplan.noaa.gov
# <- Cache-Control: no-store
# <- Pragma: no-cache
# <- Expires: Sun, 27 Jul 1997 13:00:00 GMT
# <- Content-Type: application/json
# <- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

```r
res

# Response [https://foss.nmfs.noaa.gov/apexfoss/f?p=215:200:9856386363065::NO:::]
# Date: 2019-08-12 03:37
# Status: 200
# Content-Type: application/json
# Size: 39 B
# {
#   "error":"Your session has expired"
# }
```

```r
out <- content(res)
out

# $error
# [1] "Your session has expired"
```

## I need...

To be able to use R to fill out the html/xml form, submit it, get this data into my environment as a data.frame. If that can be done by simply scraping the page or requires me to download the data, is fine. Also, I am not sure what the error message stating that "your session has expired" means.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks so much for your time!